# what if change in open interest is very high but volume is low

Tags: stocks, trading, options

in a strike price the **change in open** interest is 1300000 with volume of just 1800, what does it mean if it possible please also explain difference between volume and change in open interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open interest represents the number of contracts that exist on any given day.

In order for a trade to occur, there must be a buyer and a seller.  Each may be opening or closing the contract.  There are 4 scenarios:

> BTO and STO

Both parties are initiating a new position (one new buyer and one new seller) so open interest increases by one

> BTO and STC

If a contract owner sells to a new trader, open interest does not change (an existing contract is changing hands)

> BTC and STO

If someone short a contract buys from a new trader, open interest does not change (an existing contract is changing hands)

> BTC and STC

Both parties are closing an existing position (one previous buyer and one previous seller) so open interest declines by one

---

Because contracts can be created or destroyed throughout the trading day, change in open interest can be less than or equal to the volume traded.  It is impossible for open interest to change without trading (OI is higher than the volume)  so I suspect that you are looking at bad data or some other anomaly.

Comment: Good answer explaining the crux of the problem about this question: "It is impossible for open interest to change without trading."

Comment: BTC + STC: should the open interest decline by 2?

Comment: Suppose that there is one contract in existence.  You own it and I  am short that contract.  Therefore, open interest is ONE.  Now suppose that I buy the contract back from you.  Neither one of us has a position anymore and now there are zero contracts in existence.  The OI is now ZERO (it decreased by ONE).  If OI decreased by -2 then when we transacted the second time, there would be -1 contracts in existence and that's not possible.